# Is there a major mode for editing xkb files?

Tags: major-mode

I have a custom keyboard layout I'm often editing. This is a file stored in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, similar to the other language files there. Since none of these files have an extension Emacs opens them in fundamental mode, and I used to edit them like that, but of course this is a bit more cumbersome than it would be to edit them in a fitting major mode, but, to be honest, I'm not sure what language they are written in and can't find information clearly stating that. So I'm asking: is there a major mode for editing xkb files?

Comment: Try `c-mode` or `c++-mode`?

Comment: @NickD c-mode looks good, though I can't really tell if it's the "right" one.